# Submenu go away from menu when scroll page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with position of submenu, when I open page submenu is positioned well but problem is when I scroll page and than try to open submenu it is out of position.

[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zrinja/gtw781sv/)

```
.has-sub.parent .wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    z-index:500;
}
```

I know that this problem is caused by use of position:fixed but if I try to change that than submenu is shown behind content div, I tried to fix that with z-index, but it didn't help, any suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest your fiddle is a bit of a mess... You can't use a fixed position for your submenu. You should use "absolute" position.

I add this to your CSS to modifed a bit all your nav bar:

```
.horizontalni li {position:relative;}
.navigation {z-index:100; ;}
.has-sub.parent .wrapper {position: absolute;}
.horizontalni {overflow:visible;max-width:100%}
body {margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden;}
```

and here you have your modified example: http://jsfiddle.net/gtw781sv/1/

Hope it can help you a bit.

Edited: change overflow:hidden to overflow:auto in "body" if you want to check it with scroll-bars

Comment: .horizontalni .has-sub .has-sub1 .wrapper{left:100%} /* Updated code */

Answer (score 0):

Hi Check the **demo** here

http://jsfiddle.net/adarshkr/gtw781sv/4/

Changes done in **CSS**

```
.horizontalni .has-sub .has-sub1 .wrapper{left:100%} /* Updated code */
```

Comment: amazing... what do you actually try to achieve copying my answer and then posting it... even with my own modified fiddle? (while you changed the order of the code in the answer You forgot to change it in the fiddle). Well, if you so avid to get a few points let me know and I'll give you a few for you to enjoy.

Comment: I have just updated your code only... and positioned the has-sub1 menu to right ... So obviously i will get get your fiddle code when i update your code